# Embedded Sending and initiator needs to sign

Tags: docusignapi

I have an integration setup with DocuSign, using the APIs to create and send envelopes - all is working sa we expect.

However, as requirements have advanced, I'm now looking at the EnvelopeViews:createSender API, as this seems to meet need where we provide the native DocuSign experience embedded into our logic flow.

I'm also looking to use templates - i.e. the account has a series of predefined templates with documents, recipient roles, routing order etc defined.  I can readily create an envelope in draft status using Envelopes:Create and passing in the TemplateID and a status of "created".  This results in an envelope sitting in draft status, which I can pass to EnvelopeViews:createSender to get the view.

During initiation of the signing process, I have a nominal role of "first signer internal".  By way of example, consider a HR Letter of Offer - where the DocuSign template would contain a standard document and roles of "Approving Manager", "HR Manager" and "Candidate".  In this scenario the "first signer internal" would be the "Approving Manager".

In this case, I need to connect to DocuSign as the initiating person ("first signer"), create the envelope from the template, populate the recipient details (using the view from createSender) and then the initiator ("first signer") should sign the document.

Rather than the "fist signer" receiving the standard email to sign the document, I would rather they are directed immediately to sign the document once the envelope is sent.

i.e.

1. Leading application makes API request to create envelope from the template.
2. User is directed to the view (new browser window) to populate remaining recipients (in native DocuSign interface)
3. Initiating user is then immediately taken to signing session to sign the document(s).
4. Redirect to a URL, responsible for updating a status cache, new window then closed.

Steps 1 and 4 we're effectively already handling (albeit in a different integration flow), step 2 I can see from the API Explorer how this can be done.

It is step 3 I am struggling to see how to do.

Is this flow possible?

Regards,
David

Answer (score 0):

This flow is possible.
You will have to make three API calls:

1. Create envelope from template but leave in in draft "created" status.
2. Create sender view for which you are redirecting and let user populate recipients.
3. Create a recipient view for the user in question.

Each view has a redirect URL, which should go back to your app. between 2 and 3 you will make the new API call and then send them to the new view.

Note that there's another approach completely where you could use a special type of recipients that can add new recipients and then you will not let them use the sender view but the recipient view. That is useful if you want to restrict them from making additional changes so they can ONLY add recipients.

Also final note, for step 3 you need the correct recipientID and match the email/name for the one that is logged in and would be signing.

Comment: Hi Inbar - thanks for the reply.  All this is clear, as far as I can tell, doesn't quite achieve precisely what I'm after.  For clarity, "I" am initiating the envelope and need to sign the documents contained within.  The envelope will be based on a template.   As I understand, the Sender View when user completes will in fact send the envelope - and therefore "I" receive an email from DocuSign prompting me to sign the documents. 

Even if I redirect to a Recipient View, the completion of the Sender View generates an email to me, which isn't required if I use the Recipient View - correct?

Comment: Ideally, in the Sender View, if the first signer is that same as the user initiating the envelope, it would be nice to be able to take them directly to the signing view and then redirect back to the calling application.

Comment: not clear what issue you need my help with. You can customize any emails sent. If you provide clientUserId for a recipient - they'll not receive the initial email. The final email can be controlled from the account settings.
As for having first signer sign - that's possible too. Some of our own 1st party integrations (like DocuSign for Outlook or SharePoint) already do that. You check how the envelope is set up and if the logged in user is the next signer - you create a view and redirect it there.